# Having trouble getting two fields to concatenate

Tags: php, mysql

hostSo i know how to get the two fields to concatenate from directly inside of MYSQL, but having trouble getting it to work with my PHP.

Directly from `MYSQL = SELECT CONCAT(ConfigurationItem, ' - ', ,Buzzword) FROM Buzz;`

But how do i incorporate it into this PHP below, I have researched to no end. I want to combine the two fields ConfigurationItem and Buzzword into a field named shortdescription, without having to do it manually through MYSQL everytime the PHP is submitted.

```
 <?php
$con = mysql_connect("host","username","password");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("buzz_feed", $con);

  $sql = "INSERT INTO Buzz (BuzzID, ConfigurationItem, Buzzword, OccurrenceDate, PostingDate, TierStatus, MasterTicket) 
    VALUES 
    ('$_POST[BuzzID]','$_POST[ConfigurationItem]','$_POST[Buzzword]','$_POST[OccurrenceDate]','$_POST[PostingDate]','$_POST[TierStatus]','$_POST[MasterTicket]')";



if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }

echo "Buzz Phrase information updated";

mysql_close($con)
?>
```

Comment: Could you clarify exactly what you're having problems with?

Comment: This should help you out :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13418874/php-mysql-select-concat

Comment: There is no concat in your posted code. Nowhere are you selecting anything from the database.

Comment: Also, absolutely no validation and completely open to sql injection.

Comment: i did not put the concat in the code becuase i dont know where to put it in the code

Comment: Thank you James! Checking that now. :)

Comment: Concat is a select aggregate function.  Your code shows an insert.  Not sure what you would concat on an insert(?).

Comment: Andrew, that makes perfect sense, I just now discovered that after reading more about MYSQL functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up resolving my issue by inserting "ShortDescription" in the INSERT INTO line and then just telling it to insert the two fields I wanted together in the field "ShortDescription" and by using double spaces between my hyphen, I was able to get the desired effect I was looking for which turns out like this "Example - Example" See my code below

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO Buzz (BuzzID, ConfigurationItem, Buzzword, OccurrenceDate, PostingDate, TierStatus, MasterTicket, ShortDescription) 
    VALUES 
    ('$_POST[BuzzID]','$_POST[ConfigurationItem]','$_POST[Buzzword]','$_POST[OccurrenceDate]','$_POST[PostingDate]',
     '$_POST[TierStatus]','$_POST[MasterTicket]','$_POST[ConfigurationItem]'    ' - '    '$_POST[Buzzword]')";
```

Answer (score 0):

I've concatenated them together in php as the insert.
Although there is nothing wrong with catting them in your select statement.
In fact I'd opt for that because it is redundnant-y, you are inserting the same data twice in essence.
But this should do what you are asking for.
I have also corrected your quotation marks in the query.
Also google sql injection

```
 <?php
$con = mysql_connect("host","username","password");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("buzz_feed", $con);

  $sql = "INSERT INTO Buzz (BuzzID, ConfigurationItem, Buzzword, 
                            OccurrenceDate, PostingDate, 
                            TierStatus, MasterTicket, shortdescription) 
    VALUES 
    ('".$_POST['BuzzID']."','".$_POST['ConfigurationItem']."',
     '".$_POST['Buzzword']."','".$_POST['OccurrenceDate']."','".$_POST['PostingDate']."',
     '".$_POST['TierStatus']."','".$_POST['MasterTicket']."', 
     '".$_POST['ConfigurationItem']."' - '". $_POST['Buzzword']."')";



if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }

echo "Buzz Phrase information updated";

mysql_close($con)
?>
```